# One-word link for intranet - top level domain (tld) setup with BIND 9

Tags: local, bind, intranet, tld

While it seems to be a kind of typical pattern for the intranet ...  however haven't been able to find the right and working solution for it. I'm trying to set up the intranet site accessible by the link: http:// teamwork/ and created for this a zone file below for BIND 9. The strange thing in this configuration is that I can't access the web site by one-word link "teamwork", however once I add a dot - "teamwork." - it works! How can I get rid of the dot at the end of tld domain name so just "teamwork" in the browser address bar could work? This is my zone file for "teamwork":

```
$TTL    1d
@   IN  SOA ns.teamwork. root.srv.teamwork. (
                 20130704
                 24h
                 12m
                 8w
                 5h )
     IN NS  ns.teamwork.
ns   IN A   172.18.0.2
www  IN A   172.18.0.2
teamwork.   IN  A   172.18.0.2
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is doable, but If it is, you would need to modify your zone so that you have an "A" record without anything before it, like your ns record, so a zone "     IN A 172.18.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

Don't set up a TLD for your one word URL.

Instead add an A or CNAME record for `teamwork.example.com` (where `example.com` is your regular domain name) and make sure the clients have `example.com` in their DNS search domains. Any hostname that does not include dots* will automatically try appending the DNS search domain.

For example, if your search domain is `superuser.com` and you use `http://meta/` it will automatically go to `http://meta.superuser.com/`.

---

* Or all, depending on your resolver's configuration.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a nice solution, however how can you distribute/update DNS search domains automatically for all clients on the intranet? (and maybe with different operating systems on their computers as well) Can it be done via DHCP?

Comment: Yes, it can be done via DHCP.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I thought I configured something incorrectly in zone file, but the solution you suggested is great given it's configurable centrally with DHCP.